# How to restart running task and pending task in celery once worker is forcefully shutdown?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, flower

Currently i am running task in celery which take 10 to 15 minutes to complete but problem is How do i restart task which currently running in worker and also one which is currently not running but waiting for task to run while i forcefully stopped worker or in case my server got crash or stopped. What happens right now is if i start celery again it's not starting the last running task or remaining task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one thing you can do is enable [`acks_late`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-acks-late) on the task. Additionally, it's probably worthwhile to read their [FAQ section on acks late and retry.](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry)

```
@app.task(acks_late=True)
def task(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Comment: I tried acks_late, but when I set acks_late=True for a long running task, the task is requeued after 2 mins. I am assuming this is because the task was not acknowledged so that is why it is being requeued. This doesn't happen if I set acks_late=False. Can you please help how I can use asks_late for long running tasks

Comment: It'd be best to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to set [`acks_late`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.acks_late) and [`reject_on_worker_lost`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.reject_on_worker_lost):

```py
@app.task(bind=True, base=AbortableTask, acks_late=True, reject_on_worker_lost=True)
def my_task(self, experiment_pk: int):
   # Your code...
```

And in the `celery.py` file I made an adaptation of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mlavin/6671079) which retrieves all the pending tasks considering the `visibility_timeout` parameter (which makes the task to be waiting without being processed after a worker restart):

```py
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_init

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_proj.settings")

app = Celery("my_proj")

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

app.autodiscover_tasks()

# Gets the max between all the parameters of timeout in the tasks
max_timeout = a_vale  # This value must be bigger than the maximum soft timeout set for a task to prevent an infinity loop
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': max_timeout + 60}  # 60 seconds of margin


def restore_all_unacknowledged_messages():
    """
    Restores all the unacknowledged messages in the queue.
    Taken from https://gist.github.com/mlavin/6671079
    """
    conn = app.connection(transport_options={'visibility_timeout': 0})
    qos = conn.channel().qos
    qos.restore_visible()
    print('Unacknowledged messages restored')


@worker_init.connect
def configure(sender=None, conf=None, **kwargs):
    restore_all_unacknowledged_messages()
```